# How to ensure async operation executed during transaction has access to data written within transaction?

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, transactions

I have transaction within which I send pub/sub message. Pub/sub message handler should read data written during transaction. It seems like sometimes pub/sub handler is being executed before transaction completion which results in missing data. How can I ensure that pub/sub handler has required data?
I am using python + django and it provides `on_commit` handler which is performed after transaction committed. But if I send pub/sub message from there then it is possible that transaction commits but for whatever reason sending pub/sub message fails and then I end up in a state when database is updated but pub/sub handler was never executed. Any other mechanism I can use for this?

Comment: PG's native [NOTIFY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-notify.html) and [LISTEN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-listen.html) do exactly what you want; it's not clear if that's what you're currently using.

Comment: @AdamKG This seems like indeed what I can use, I was not aware of this functionality. thanks!